# VBA userform: application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, userform, worksheet

I copied a code that worked well in VBA module to UserForm since I need to combine some actions defined in userform. Now I got stuck when executing the following part, with error message 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

```
Sub test()
    Dim Myworkbook As workbook
    Dim Myid As Variant

    Set Myworkbook = ThisWorkbook

    Myid=1

    Myref=FinRef(Myworkbook, "Ref", Myid)
End Sub

    Function FinRef(myfile As Workbook, InputSheet As String, Ref_ID As Variant) 

        Dim I, k, LinkFrom, Description As Integer
        Dim Linkdescrip As String

        FinRef = ""

        LinkFrom = 1           
        Description = 8             
        Linkdescrip = 7             
        For I = 2 To 3000
            k = myfile.Sheets(InputSheet).Cells(I, LinkFrom)

            If k = Ref_ID Then
                FinRef = FinRef & myfile.Sheets(InputSheet).Cells(I, Linkdescrip) & myfile.Sheets(InputSheet).Cells(I, Description)
            End If
        Next I

    End Function
```

Though there are lots of ppl who experienced the same problem, I couldn't find solution fit for me. Any tips?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which line do you get the error on?

Comment: What procedure are the first 5 lines in?  They'd be invalid outside of a procedure.

Comment: @Dave It's the line ' FinRef = FinRef & myfile.Sheets(InputSheet).Cells(I, Linkdescrip) & myfile.Sheets(InputSheet).Cells(I, Description)'

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The first 5 lines are defined within a sub procedure and the function is defined outside the sub procedure.

Comment: I get `Argument not optional` as `FinRef` is the name of a function - so `FinRef = FinRef(.....)` isn't going to work.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook My mistake. It's a different name in my code. What do you get if you use a different name?

Comment: I get `variable not defined` :) .... ok, after I've defined it I get `Duplicate declaration in current scope` as you've defined `InputSheet` twice (once in the function header and once in the body).

Comment: Also -  `LinkFromRisk` isn't defined anywhere.  `Description` is an `Integer` - you could get an overflow error with that, better to use `Long`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Oh, another mistake when editing the post... I had this corrected in my code but still got the same error.

Comment: Sorry.... what's `Inputfile`?

Comment: `Dim I, k, LinkFrom, Description As Integer` declares 3 variants and only 1 integer. I doubt that was you intent. Also, please post a [mcve] which people can actually run to see your exact error. There seems to be a disconnect between your question and your actual problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for the tips. I tried to simplify the problem only to the place where I got error from the original code. Agree that it became confusing. The question is as defined in the post that I got this error only when I use the same code in a UserForm instead of a module. Both the original and the current code are under the same VBA project (deleted the code in module after copying to userform).

Comment: Using an explicit workbook variable only makes much sense when your code is designed to run in a context in which more than one workbook is open. Perhaps `ThisWorkbook` isn't the workbook you want? The reason I'm saying that is that `ThisWorkbook` is context-dependent and you are describing code that breaks when the context changes. Without being able to reproduce the problem it isn't possible to do much more than guess.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right John, the workbook I used wasn't ThisWorkbook as in the posted code. Now it works after following declare all variables correctly as you pointed out. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John said - your code as posted doesn't produce the error you're reporting.

**I think the problem with your code is:**
`Dim Linkdescrip As String` should be `Dim Linkdescrip As Long`.

Turned into working code:
`?thisworkbook.Worksheets("Ref").cells(2,"7")` returns your error.
`?thisworkbook.Worksheets("Ref").cells(2,7)` returns the value from range `G2`.

---

Having said that, I think I can see what you're after:
Column `A` of the `Ref` sheet is populated with numbers, you want to search that column for a specific number and if it's found find return the values from columns `G` & `H` on that row.

This code will find the numeric value `1` within column `A` of the sheet named `Ref` in the workbook that contains the code (`ThisWorkbook`).  It will then return the values from columns `G:H` of that row, or it will return an empty string.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyRef As String

    MyRef = FinRef(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ref"), 1)

End Sub

Public Function FinRef(InputSheet As Worksheet, Ref_ID As Long) As String

    Dim rFound As Range

    With InputSheet
        Set rFound = .Columns(1).Find( _
            What:=Ref_ID, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            FinRef = rFound.Offset(, 6) & rFound.Offset(, 7)
        End If

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have declared Linkdescrip As Long and it works!